# Reload a Form through another Form by Button click

Tags: c#, winforms, button, form-load

I have two forms: `Form1` and `Form2`.

On `Form1` I have a button. And through that button I want to reload the `Form2`.
On `From2_Load` event I've some code which will update the picture on every load.

But I'm unable to accomplish the task.
I'm using this code to reload, but failed to do that.

This is my 'On button click' event code:

```
Form2 frm = new from2();
frm.refresh();
```

I don't want to hide the `Form2`. I just want to close it and reopen it on each click.

Comment: `Refresh` only does the paint-job for you .If u are adding something/some data/some control in the form and u want to update the UI(my assumption),u have several options open..But before i describe them,is my assumption correct ?

Comment: i want to update the picture in picturebox

Comment: Don't reload the form, that's an app, not a website. Even modern website are no longer reloading pages, instead they're using Ajax to only update the section of the page that needs updating. Move the code that you have in `From2_Load` to a separate function, and call it from `From2_Load` and from button's click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you have some code in your `Form_Load` event...
Why not do this?

```
private void form2_Load()
{
Mycodes()///call it if required
}

public void MyCodes() 
{
  // Move codes from load event to here
}

// Now from Form1
public class form1
{
 Form2 frm = new Form2() ///make sure u declare it in class level
private void Bttn_Click()
{
    frm.MyCodes();
}
```

Comment: Let me test it.

Comment: Make sure to upvote and mark it as answer if it helped :)

Comment: You forgot to call `MyCodes()` in the `From2_Load`. Also you need to make `MyCodes()` public otherwise you will not be able to call `Form2.MyCodes()` in the first form.

Comment: Hi. Ok it's working. but it's creating the new instance each time. and i want to get only one instance.. i mean i don't want multiple windows..

Comment: Tnx @RacilHilan ... I was in a rush...Totally missed it

Comment: What do u mean it's creating multiple windows ??

Comment: Sorry! it wasn't relevant. @zackraiyan Thanks it worked.

Comment: @RacilHilan , i guess his problem was he was calling `Form2 frm  = new From2` on the button click which he should've done in class level..That's why he always had a new instance whenever he clicked the button...But glad we could help him

Comment: @zackraiyan upvote my question if you think it can help any one else.

Comment: Though i upvoted it, make sure to provide relevant codes in future for better assistance :)